# Use the async modifier to prefix a delegate

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

In the book **Microsoft Visual C# Step by Step** says in chapter 24:

> **Tip** You can use the async modifier to prefix a delegate, making it
> possible to create delegates that incorporate asynchronous processing
> by using the await operator.

I'm trying to declare a delegate with the async modifier and the code doesn't compile, what am I doing wrong? Or I misunderstand the author. **How to declare an asynchronous delegate**?

```
async delegate Task MyDelegate();
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: `async` is *not* part of the method signature in IL. The keyword is only valid on a method implementation. As it only indicates that the C# compiler should translate your method implementation into a coroutine / state machine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot use `async` with delegate *types*, but you can with the delegates themselves. E.g., using the more modern lambda syntax: `var d = async () => await Task.Yield();`

Answer (score 2):

I think what the author means is something like this

```
MyDelegate d = 
    async () => await Task.Delay(1000); //delegate with async prefix

await d();
```

with a delegate definition like so:
`delegate Task MyDelegate();`